# PDFファイルを作成した際、フォント情報が肥大してしまう

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

アプリ内部に保存しているPDFファイルとUIImageをMargeさせてから
新たなPDFファイルを作成したいです。

※ vfr/Readerのライブラリを使用しています

```
ReaderDocument *document = [[ReaderDocument alloc] initWithFilePath:SamplePdfPath] password:nil];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newPdfPath, CGRectZero, nil);

for (NSInteger page = 1; page <= [[document pageCount] integerValue]; page++) 
{
    ReaderContentPage *contentPage = [[ReaderContentPage alloc] initWithURL:document.fileURL page:page password:nil];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(contentPage.bounds, nil);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, contentPage.getPageRef);

       if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:drawFilePath]) {
           NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:drawFilePath];
           [[UIImage imageWithData:imgData] drawAsPatternInRect:contentPage.bounds];
       }
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

この処理で作成したPDFファイルを解析すると、 フォント情報が元PDFファイルの2倍になっていました。

おそらくこれが起因して、作成した PDFファイルのサイズが約1.5倍になってしまいます。

フォント情報を元ファイルと同じ数にするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？